# Passing GET parameter to a weird URL pattern (RetroFit 1.9)

Tags: android, rest, get, retrofit

Please excuse the title; I was not sure how to describe this problem:

I have a REST service URL that looks like:

```
@GET("/ProfileData/CustomerDetails('1234')?$format=json")
CustomerDetailsResponse getContactDetails();
```

Here, "1234" is the ID for the customer and I need to pass this in getContactDetails().

How would I go about this with RetroFit 1.9? (can't update to 2.0 just yet).

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand your question as very little details are given 
It will be good if you pass your values in this way

```
@GET("/ProfileData/CustomerDetails?id=1234?format=json")
Call<enter> getvalue(@Query("id")String id ,@Query("json") String json)`
```

For displaying values you can take help from this code

```
Call<Student> call = service.getDetails();


call.enqueue(new Callback<Student>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Student> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        try {
             String check;
            text_status_1.setText("StudentId  :  " + response.body().getC_name());
                     //text_status_1.setText("Status  :  " + StudentData.get(i). getC_name());
                     //text_city_2.setText("city  : " + StudentData.get(i).getCity());
                       check=response.body().getStatus();

}
```